# How to set my custom launcher as default launcher programatically [Rooted device]?

Tags: android

[image]How can forcefully show my launcher as default launcher[Without any popup's even user press on Home button choose launcher popup should not show]
How to forcefully press on **ALWAYS** through programatically

Comment: That doesn't sound like something I'd want on my phone, but fair question. +1

Comment: This is like making our own launcher instead of using custom launchers.For that i made my device rooted.